# convert multiple json objects to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am new to python and having trouble with something that seems conceptually very simple. I've read a number of SO posts but still can't solve my problem(s).

I have a function to convert amazon reviews to json format. Each review becomes a single json object. I would like to compile all reviews in a single dataframe, with the json keys as columns and each review in a row.

There are a large number of reviews, each formatted like so:

```
{
"product/productId": "B00006HAXW",
"product/title": "Winnie the Pooh",
"product/price": "unknown",
"review/userId": "A1RSDE90N6RSZF",
"review/profileName": "piglet",
"review/helpfulness": "9/9",
"review/score": "5.0",
"review/time": "1042502400",
"review/summary": "Love this book", 
"review/text" : "Exciting stories about highly intelligent creatures, very inspiring!"
}
```

How can I compile all reviews into a pandas dataframe? I'm having two separate problems:

1. How do I compile all reviews in one object? Currently, the output is generated like so:

   ```
   for e in parse("reviews.txt.gz"):
       print json.dumps(e)
   ```

I tried creating an empty `list` and using `append`:

```
    for e in parse("reviews.txt.gz"):
        revs = []
        revs = revs.append(json.dumps(e))
```

but that does not work - `print revs` prints out

```
None
None
None
```

2. When I use `pd.read_json` on a single review formatted as above, it returns "If using all scalar values, you must must pass an index".  Does this mean I do not have valid json format data?

Comment: Looks like you're re-initializing an empty list with `revs = []` for every loop, then re-assigning `revs` to the output of a `list.append` call (which is `None`; `list.append` modifies the original `list`). Additionally, you likely don't need the `json.dumps(e)` call, you want a list of _python_ objects not _json_ objects.

Comment: Is the bit `parse("reviews.txt.gz")` working? is that what produces the example json you posted?

Comment: @cphlewis Yes, the sample json formatted review is what is produced by `parse("file")`.

Comment: @jeff of course, must initialize list outside loop. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is no need to call `json.dumps()` on the data as this returns a string and you can pass python objects to Pandas.

Your for loop should look like

```
revs = []
for e in parse("reviews.txt.gz"):
    revs = revs.append(e)
```

But unless parse is a generator (ie. uses the `yield` keyword), you can just set `revs = parse("reviews.txt.gz")`

2. `pd.read_json` attempts to parse the json as a DataFrame... If you only have one column then, this will throw an error as it expects the data to be doubly indexed.

So if `revs` is now a list of strings (ie. your parse function returns json representations of the data), you can call

```
df = pd.read_json(revs)
```

Otherwise if revs is now a list of dictionaries (ie. your parse function has already interpreted the json and returns dictionaries of the data), you can call

```
df = pd.DataFrame(revs)
```

Comment: Thanks @Alex !!  Parse is a generator. Removing the call to json.dumps and initializing revs outside the loop solved problem 1. And as that produced a list of dictionaries, calling pd.DataFrame solved problem 2.